# Batch file with CPDF to multi files

Tags: batch-file, pdf, cmd

i am using this command in cmd with cpdf.

```
cpdf -split a.pdf -o page %%%pdf
```

but I wanted to use it for a pdf list in a directory.

ie you need a batch script that runs on all pdf files in the directory and the cpdf split command is applied to each file dividing by one per sheet.

example, transform the files:

```
a.pdf
b.pdf
c.pdf
```

and more ...

in several files, 1 per page of the original with the name of the original

```
a1.pdf
a2.pdf
a3.pdf

b1.pdf
b2.pdf
b3.pdf

c1.pdf
c2.pdf
c3.pdf
```

and more ...

can help?

Comment: What about the `forfiles` Windows command?

Comment: sorry, but can you give an example of the code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `cpdf` syntax, but `for %a in (*.pdf) do echo %a` should give you a start. (command line syntax. For use in a batch file, use `%%a` instead of `%a` both times)

Comment: ok. done like this. for %%f in (*.pdf) do cpdf -split %%f -o %%f_page%%%.pdf

Comment: add your comment to the question, so that future readers have the full context. Did it solve your problem, if so, consider adding it as the accepted answer.